# Can React components be injected at run time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My project contains some features A,B,C where we have Component from each feature.
These features can be accessed by users if they purchased licesences for each feature.
In this case user1 might purchases licesences for feature A,B. while user2 might purchases licesences for features A,B,C. 
I am trying to protect the code base (the build) so it does not have code for features not purchased by users.
in this case do I have to create 8 builds?
1. build for A,B,C
2. build for A
3. build for B
4. build for C
5. build for A,B
7. build for A,C
8. build for B,C

Or is there any way to inject React components at run time, after fetching them from endpoint?

Comment: Can you show us some examples?  Not sure what you mean by 'fetching them from endpoint'.

Comment: Are you looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html ?

Answer (score 2):

If user has grant for specific component then you can send your componetns as json object and using this library (https://github.com/pravdomil/react-serialize#readme) you are able to deserialize your object to react component.